Should I delete this (originally incorrect) answer?
I recently answered a question. It bombed horribly, as I’m sure everyone knows by now, because the sources I used blatantly lied, and I couldn’t test for myself.
Should I just delete the answer?

I left a comment explaining the situation, since I felt now that the answer was gone, there should be some indication of why a random minecraft question got so much attention.

It's up to you what action you want to take. If you want it deleted, a mod might have to do it for you as it is the accepted answer. (Let me know if you want me to do that).
Alternatively, I'd remove the strikethrough text entirely, and just state something like:

I was initially wrong, mislead by incorrect sources. It is not possible to breed fish, as stated by the Minecraft wiki


Note that the answer is still in positive-rep territory: 4 upvotes = 40 rep, 12 downvotes = -24 rep. Deleting it you'll lose 16 rep.

It is unaccepted now, so they could delete it now if they so wished. It would get them the peer pressure badge

@Robotnik I'm just going to delete it. It's close enough to neutral/negative rep that I don't care, and the other answers are better anyway. Thanks for the help.

@Daemons no problem, glad to be of help :)
